# Execute custom code in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there a way I can execute custom code in c# when a user clicks a button in the CRM application? I would like it a synchronous and asynchronous approach.
Actually something like when putting a button on a webform with a wired code behind click event handler.
And how can I add a button?
I want to display a list of report views the customer has assembled and access the report data in the CRM database.

It seems so complicated with CRM! 
Here's an example of a custom workflow with a bunch of XAML. I dont know where they got it from.

[Sample: Create a workflow in code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh913611(v=crm.7).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it:

1. Use [Ribbon WorkBench](https://www.develop1.net/public/Download%20Ribbon%20Workbench%202013.aspx) add add a button to the form. Only supported way of adding buttons to CRM is by editing ribbon XML.
2. Add an on click JavaScript [Event Handler](https://mahenderpal.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/calling-java-script-on-click-of-command-button-ms-crm-2015-step-by-step/).
3. Call an [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481600.aspx) which can be used to call a custom workflow where you can perform business logic.

Comment: Thanks, should I go with VS2013? Because the CRM 2015 SDK does not contain a developer toolkit! We use CRM2015.